# What is the meaning of this notation?

Tags: math, notation

[image: T notation]

I have seen this notation in the book Schaums-Outline a couple of times now and I can't quite understand it. I'd very much appreciate if someone explained what it means. I am thinking that it means Transform, as in the input goes in the system and transforms? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means "the transformation that turns $x$ into $y$."

You might also see $\mathbf{T}^{-1}$ which means the inverse: turning $y$ into $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and also for the extra information.

Comment: It's very common to have `letter-openingcurlybracket-function-closingcurlybracket` denote an integral transform, such as the common Fourier Trafo notation $\mathcal F\left\{x(t)\right\}(f)$; the $(t)$ and $(f)$ are often even left out, because they just explicitly state the free variable's symbol before and after transformation, so $\mathcal F\left\{x\right\}=X(f)$ is pretty common.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, an electrical circuit is as an **operator**, i.e., a function that takes a function and returns another function. Let this operator be denoted by $\mathcal T$, let $x : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the input signal and let $y := \mathcal T (x)$ be the output signal. Let $\mathcal D_{t_0}$ be the delay operator that delays its input by $t_0 > 0$.

Translating the equation on your book to this language, we obtain

$$(\mathcal T \circ \mathcal D_{t_0}) (x) = \mathcal D_{t_0} (y) = (\mathcal D_{t_0} \circ \mathcal T) (x)$$

which holds for all input signals $x$. Hence, $\mathcal T \circ \mathcal D_{t_0} = \mathcal D_{t_0} \circ \mathcal T$, i.e., operators $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal D_{t_0}$ **commute**. Thus, the electrical circuit corresponding to operator $\mathcal T$ is **time-invariant**.

Answer (score 3):

Since the word did not appear in previous answers, I would suggest the meaning of "**transfer**" function. Systems theory is globally about relationship between inputs, outputs, and some process in-between, sometimes called an [input–process–output (IPO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model) model:

> The input–process–output (IPO) model, or input-process-output pattern,
>   is a widely used approach in systems analysis ... resources, money or
>   information, transformed into outputs, such as consumables, services,
>   new information or money.

So the idea of a transform/transformation is at its core. 
More specifically in engineering, one sometimes uses the notion of [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function):

> In engineering, a transfer function (also known as system function
>   or network function of an **electronic** or control **system component**, is a
>   mathematical function giving the corresponding output value for each
>   possible value of the input to the device

which I believe is appropriate too in your concept. See for instance SE [How to interpret the notation of a transfer function](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25652/how-to-interpret-the-notation-of-a-transfer-function?rq=1). Aside, $T$ is a common notation for an [**integral transform**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform):

> In mathematics, an integral transform is any transform $T$ of the
>   following form: $$ (Tf)(u)=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}K(t,u)\,f(t)\,dt$$